# Xamarin.Forms and Plugin.Media: after about 20 photos something crashes

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem with `Xamarin.Forms` ver. 2.3.4.224 and `Plugin.Media` ver. 2.6.2. The problem occurs after taking about 20 photos (depends from the device): basically the app crashes without any apparently reason.

If you want to replicate the error, I created a test project for you on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/XamarinCameraTest). With my iPad Air or iPad Pro after about 30 photos (video [iPad Air](https://youtu.be/od0Qx5YdMo0) - [iPad Pro](https://youtu.be/0IReKcFyPcc)). All devices are iOS ver. 10.3.1 and they have enough space to storage photos.

The app is very simple: you have two buttons one for taking a picture and the other one to pick a photo. If you take photos one after another, after about 20 (32 in an iPad Air) the app crashes. I'm just take photos with the `Plugin.Media` nothing more.

Any ideas are welcome.

### Update

In my project I had a reference to `Refractored.MvvmHelpers` and I noticed if I remove it, I can take more pictures. I created my `BaseViewModel` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I noticed I can take more photos.

I created then a new project (you can find it on GitHub under [**cameratesteasy**](https://github.com/erossini/XamarinCameraTest/tree/master/cameratesteasy/cameratesteasy)) without MVVM and there is just the code to take a photo like:

```
public partial class cameratesteasyPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public cameratesteasyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    }

    void UpdateCount()
    {
        count++;
        CountLabel.Text = $"{count} times";
    }

    async void StartCameraTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        using (var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                          new StoreCameraMediaOptions {}))
        {
            if (file == null)
                return;

            UpdateCount();
        }
    }

    async void StartCameraTakeTapped(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

        if (file == null)
            return;

        UpdateCount();
    }
}
```

In this case the app shut down after 52 photos. I saved the log for `Xcode` and you can see it [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/files/910519/crash.cameratest2.txt).

I used `Xamarin Profile` and the memory level is always low. After about 30 photos, an error occurs in `Xamarin Profiler`

[image: Xamarin Profiler error]

[image: Xamarin Profiler error 2]
[image: Xamarin Profiler error 3]

Finally I could create a `Xamarin Profiler` [file](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/files/910609/cameratest.profiler.mlpd.zip)

Also I noticed this kind of error occurs on iPads. The same app in an iPhone is working fine (apparently) or I didn't find up to now the number of photos before crashing.

### Update /2

I decided to implement a native function for taking photo.

**Interface**

```
public interface ICamera
{
    void TakePicture();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
using System;
using cameratest.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Camera_iOS))]
namespace cameratest.iOS
{
    public class Camera_iOS : ICamera
    {
        static UIImagePickerController picker;
        static Action<NSDictionary> _callback;

        static void Init()
        {
            if (picker != null)
                return;

            picker = new UIImagePickerController();
            picker.Delegate = new CameraDelegate();
        }

        class CameraDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
        {
            public override void FinishedPickingMedia(
                                 UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
            {
                var cb = _callback;
                _callback = null;

                picker.DismissModalViewController(true);
                cb(info);
            }
        }

        public static void TakePicture(UIViewController parent, 
                                       Action<NSDictionary> callback)
        {
            Init();
            picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
            _callback = callback;
            parent.PresentModalViewController(picker, true);
        }

        public static void SelectPicture(UIViewController parent, 
                                         Action<NSDictionary> callback)
        {
            Init();
            picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            _callback = callback;
            parent.PresentModalViewController(picker, true);
        }

        public void TakePicture()
        {
            var rc = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            TakePicture(rc, (obj) =>
            {
                var photo = obj.ValueForKey(
                         new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")) as UIImage;
                var documentsDirectory = 
                         Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                // hardcoded filename, overwritten each time
                string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, 
                         "Photo.jpg");
                NSData imgData = photo.AsJPEG();
                NSError err = null;
                if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("saved as " + jpgFilename);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as " + 
                         jpgFilename + " because" + err.LocalizedDescription);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With this code after about 30 photos, the app crashes. The only difference is with this code I can receive some alert from `ReceiveMemoryWarning`. If you have an interest, I updated the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/XamarinCameraTest).

Comment: Sounds like a memory problem. You could use the Xamarin Profiler to see what happens with the memory after adding a photo. After you have identified that as the problem you should find a way to avoid the memory filling up.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis. I updated my post with some new info

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I'm getting 100 mb memory increase every time I'm opening the camera to take an image.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm display a memory alert to the user, that's it. This bug is a nightmare for me and my users